# Is sorting or inserting more efficient with joining arrays of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have multiple objects with a field called "num". Num can be any number between 1000000000 to 10000000005. I want to ensure that if I have x number of lists, all lists need to be combined in array1 in sorted ascending order based on the "num" property.

If I start with an array like this "

```
array1": [{item:23532532, num:1000000520},{item:23523, num:1000000620},{item:346346432, num:1000000620}]
```

I have a second array

```
"array2": [{item:23532, num:....},{item:3623, num:....}]
```

Assuming array2 is in sorted order by "num", is it more efficient to:

1) Add Then Sort Whole - Loop through every item in "array2" and add it to the end of "array1", then do a javascript built in "sort" function on the "num" property on the entire array?

2) Insert Into Right Place - Loop through every item in "array2" and use "if" conditions to check to see if the "num" value is greater than the current item in "array2", if so, then insert the element before that index via "splice". (No javascript built-in array sort used)

Or is there a more efficient method? Pseudocode or sample code is a plus.

Comment: The values for *num* in the example (e.g. 1000000520) seem to be outside the range specified (1000000000 to 1000000005).

Comment: "1000000000 to 1000000005" doesn't include your examples (such as                 1000000520).

Comment: Additionally, what you've described in #2 **is** a sort :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: `splice` is probably pretty inefficient. I'd go with the simple solution (concat + sort) first, then if that is not good enough use sort(small) + merge

Comment: I would join the two arrays using *splice* (or *concat*), then sort the whole. But a few minutes testing on [*jsperf*](https://jsperf.com) would answer your question. I expect splicing individual members would only make sense if you add a few from time to time.

Comment: @RobG: You probably meant `push` or `concat`, not `splice`?

Comment: How many items are you actually talking about? It might not make an observable difference at all.

Comment: @Bergi—I was thinking of using *splice* like *concat*, but clearly concat is the better option here.

Comment: Are BOTH arrays sorted, or only one of them? If they're both sorted, then a merge sort would actually be very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I measured the results from three different algorithms in three different browsers.**

Two things are true about all performance related questions:

1. If you really want to know the answer, **you've got to test** your specific algorithm in several browsers to really answer the question.
2. Many performance related questions are **actually not material** in the given context in which they are being used so worrying about them until you know you need to worry about them is nothing more than time wasted on premature optimization or even unnecessary optimization.  So, before working on a specific area of performance, you should know that it matters and know that it's worth spending time on.

That said, here are some measurements for three algorithms.  This assumes you start with two arrays of objects, each sorted independently by one particular numeric property that is present in each object.

Here's the jsperf: http://jsperf.com/concat-sort-vs-insert-sort/5 that has the code for each of the three algorithms.

**Algorithm 1 is concatenate and then sort the concatenated array.**  In JS, it's nothing more than:

```
var result = arr1.concat(arr2);
result.sort(sortByNum);
```

**Algorithm 2 is an attempt at an insertion sort.**  The basic idea is to loop through the second array and for each item in that array, find where to insert it into the first array.  Since both arrays are sorted, we only have to start looking for a place to insert the next item into the first array at the place after where we inserted the last item.

**Algorithm 3 is a merge sort.**  The idea here is that you create an empty result array and two indexes, one for each of the two source arrays.  For the value at each source index, you push into the result the lower of the two items and then increase its source index.  When either source index is exhausted, you push in the rest of the other array.  I was guessing that it would be more efficient than the insertion sort because it doesn't have to insert items into the middle of an array, just add onto the end which is likely a faster operation.

---

To run a test, I created two arrays that each contain 100 objects.  Each object has a numeric property that is assigned a random number between 0 and 100,000.  Each of the two source arrays are then pre-sorted.  Each algorithm is then tested on these two source arrays.

And, here are the results:

[image]

Here's the code for the merge sort algorithm:

```
function mergeSort(arr1, arr2) {
    var result = [];
    var index1 = 0;
    var index2 = 0;
    if (!arr1.length) {
        return arr2.slice(0);
    } else if (!arr2.length) {
        return arr1.slice(0);
    }
    while (true) {
        if (arr1[index1].num <= arr2[index2].num) {
            result.push(arr1[index1]);
            ++index1;
            // see if we reached the end of the array
            if (index1 >= arr1.length) {
                result.push.apply(result, arr2.slice(index2));
                break;
            }
        } else {
            result.push(arr2[index2]);
            ++index2;
            // see if we reached the end of the array
            if (index2 >= arr2.length) {
                result.push.apply(result, arr1.slice(index1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mja1c13d/

Comment: I found a flaw in the jsPerf test of the `insertionSort()` method (it wasn't starting with a fresh copy of the `arr1` each time).  That flaw has been fixed and the results have been updated.

Comment: Your combine sort I've usually seen called a merge sort, and is a definite winner IF both source arrays are sorted. OP wasn't clear about that (still waiting on a answer there). Excellent demonstration.

Comment: That's not called a "combine sort" but a simple [merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) step.

Comment: Instead of `arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2.slice(i));` consider `return arr1.concat(arr2.slice(i))`, which also obviates the *break* (but might have no impact on speed). An insert really needs an index to get to the right location quickly.

Comment: Notice that your jsperf was broken as it has a spelling mistake in `sortByNum`. [I've fixed it](http://jsperf.com/concat-sort-vs-insert-sort/2) and also published a [version with different array lengths](http://jsperf.com/concat-sort-vs-insert-sort/4)

Comment: The problem here is that by far the most expensive operation is the sort, so by forcing the concat method to do a sort that the others don't have to do, the results are skewed. Moving the sort inside the functions makes the concat method as fast as the "combine" method (because it only does one sort of all the members, combine does two sorts of half the members).

Comment: @Bergi - I edited the jsperf to fix the mispelling and updated the results graph to show the new result.  One thing I've not figured out is how to verify your jsperf is actually doing what you expect it to do.  You can't analyze/test results or that impacts the timing.  I verified results with special test code to analyze the results in a separate jsFiddle, but then made a typo in transferring that to the jsperf.  Also changed terminology to `mergeSort()`.

Comment: @RobG - I don't understand what you mean by "moving the sort inside the functions makes the concat method as fast as the combine method"?  What algorithm are you suggesting or are you just saying that that is what the mergeSort is already doing?

Comment: @jfriend00—just evening out performance. The concat method doesn't benefit from sorted input, the others do hugely but the sorting effort is outside the functions and not being measured. If it's included, things are much more even. Performance is greatly improved if sorting can be avoided. If sorting is required for all methods, it should be included in the time.

Comment: @RobG - that depends upon what the question is.  I was under the impression that the question was asking about the fastest way to merge two already sorted arrays, not the fastest way to end up with a sorted merge regardless of how the input was originally ordered.  There are situations where the input could have been previously sorted as part of other operations or the input was constructed in a sorted way so the time to sort it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in sort is likely to be substantially more efficient than writing your own insertion-sort in **most cases**. If that weren't so, then the native `Array.sort()` would be written to do this itself.

However, you could be looking at one of the exceptions, depending on the size of the two arrays. If you know that one of the two arrays is already sorted, AND the other (unsorted) array is short, AND the total size of the two arrays is large, then iterating through the short array and inserting into the large, sorted one may be more efficient.

Inserting (given that you know one list is already sorted) is going to be on the order of `N1 * N2`; concatenating and sorting is probably something like `(N1 + N2) log (N1 + N2)`. Depending on those two relative sizes, it could go either way.

But unless your lists are very large, the difference is going to be below the threshold of humanly noticeable, so code maintainability argues for 'concatenate and sort'. Actual real performance measurements trump guesses, always, and performance is very subject to specifics of the data - so if you're really concerned, write both and test them using real data.

Comment: ＋1 especially for the last paragraph, this cannot be emphasized enough

Comment: Inserting into a large sorted array is likely only faster if an index has been kept so a b–tree search (or even a very simple grouping index) can locate the index to insert at, then update the index and array. Otherwise I'd expect the built–in sort to be faster. But of course, only testing will prove that (and it might be different in different browsers, and depend on the size of the arrays).

Comment: @RobG - Mostly agreed. If the sorted array was large AND the number of items to be inserted was very small, I think it MIGHT beat re-sorting the entire list...depending on whether the particular native implementation of `Array.sort()` is one that benefits from working on a mostly-sorted list. Which falls into the category of 'largely unknowable without testing', which really just brings us back around to 'if you really need to know, test it under your actual conditions.'

Comment: @SMcCrohan—I think that sorting algorithms have been done to death and so are incredibly optimised. Sorting a mostly sorted list ***should*** be blazing fast, so it's almost not worth the effort to find out if an indexed insert is any faster. Interesting topic to follow–up though. I seem to recall that tree indexes (did some work on quad–trees in early GIS days) were a lot of work to maintain, so only useful if they provided tangible benefits (they have huge benefits for large geographic datasets).

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't think this will match your data perfectly well and is therefore likely not useful to you, it is worth mentioning a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) executes in linear time. If you knew in advance that you needed to sort integers without gaps in the data such that an object exists for every integer between 1000000000 and 10000000005 and all integers are unique, then you can exploit this by doing a math calculation to reduce 1000000000 to position zero, 1000000001 to position 1, etc... you get there by subtracting 1000000000 from each number to get the index in the zero-based array.

You end up with something like

```
var array = new Array(9000000005); //10000000005 - 1000000000
var obj = {"item":23532532, "num":1000000520};
var array[1000000520 - 1000000000] = obj; //goes into index 520
```

The subtraction operation brings your linear time complexity to 2n instead of just n. The built in Javascript sort is likely n log n time complexity. From 0 to 100 on an x-y coordinate graph, n log n is better, but at x > 100, the 2n scales ahead in performance. For 9 billion items however unrealistic this actually is for Javascript, you can see the difference over time will be drastically improved.

It's tough to capture the scale of this graph, but this gives a good idea of the comparison... `y=x` represents counting sort, `y=2x` represents counting sort with a subtraction operation. `y = x log x` likely represents the built-in Javascript array sort.

[image]

Comment: The counting sort is a valuable answer, but your explanation of complexity classes fails to add anything useful. Btw, `O(2n) == O(n)`

Comment: @Bergi I updated the graph to remove big O notation.

Comment: Sample data has duplicate numbers, but I don't know if that was intentional. Regardless, a nice technique to have documented.